# Combine two dsl lines with different routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, proxy, adsl

I wonder if someone could offer some advice. I've been looking around the Internet for a while, but have not been able to find the right info.

I'm moving into a house with an existing dsl line. I am currently renting my own, and due to a contract I have with the phone company, I can't discontinue my subscription, but they said they would be able to transfer my line to the new house.

So, I have two dsl lines, three wifi dsl routers, and a PC I can use as a server. Is there a way I can combine these to get one wifi network with connection to both dsl lines? I would like to get them to share load, so that I have a faster overall connection, but a load balancing situation would not be an unacceptable compromise.

Comment: possible duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/147459/is-it-possible-to-combine-the-bandwidth-from-a-dsl-modem-and-a-clearwire-modem, http://superuser.com/questions/552645/how-do-i-optimize-bandwidth-throughput-using-two-dsl-lines-in-a-home-environment, http://superuser.com/questions/456328/how-to-bond-two-different-internet-connections, http://superuser.com/questions/240122/can-i-combine-two-lans-into-one-to-get-double-speed, http://superuser.com/questions/87625/can-i-use-2-internet-connection-onto-1-pc-using-switch

Comment: more possible dups: http://superuser.com/questions/577289/how-to-connect-2-lan-each-one-with-its-own-dsl-connection, http://superuser.com/questions/91177/how-can-i-unite-two-lan-connections-on-one-network, http://superuser.com/questions/417673/internet-connection-using-2-modem-at-a-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like pfSense on your server; You would need 3 NICs (2 for the WAN connections and 1 to attach your WiFi AP too).

Then you could take your remaining 2 WiFi AP and use them to repeat the wireless signal for a greater range

https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Multi-WAN_2.0

Answer (score 0):

You need a load balancing router. It'll do all the work for you then. PFsense box would work too, but really that'd be a fair bit of work and typically uses a fair bit of mains power too.

This is specific to a TP link model but it gives a good idea of how it would work with any model:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDUfP8a5zNY

The bit before 5mins onwards is the important stuff.